# Difference between: <br/> vs. <br/>=20

Tags: html, eml

Can somebody explain the difference between the following html tags?

```
<br/>
```

and

```
<br/>
=20
```

I found the latter in some .eml but the two seem to do the same when rendered as an .eml message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=20` isn't part of the tag, it's just text that follows after the `<br/>` tag.

Was the message encoded as `html/quoted-printable`? In quoted-printable format, `=` is used to introduce special sequences. When it's followed up two hexadecimal digits, it's replaced with the character with that code. So `=20` represents a <kbd>space</kbd> character.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Yes, from the message it looks like it was set to Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable. I'm no .eml expert so I'm just trying to find why an html section of these emails were not rendering html correctly.  Turns out that ">" where being encoded to &gt; but previous known good working output where not converting the ">" but were also including <br/>=20 for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

0x20 is the hexidecimal ascii code for space.  I suspect some encoding process replaced 'space' with '=20'.  The rendered output will look the same.

Comment: yes, you are correct. there is an parser that was adding those tokens based on an apparent reg ex.  thanks again for the reply.